# Getting wrong tags in rfid scan

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, nfc, rfid

I'm getting strange results in scanning rfid tags with a [RDM630](http://img.inkfrog.com/click_enlarge1.php?image=9.jpg&username=jelly0115&aid=299992282) on a Raspberry Pi with Python.
I'm not a professional so maybe you can figure out my mistake easily.

The tags are recognized mostly fine, but it seems like I have some kind of loop in there.
For example if I use tag1 and tag2 alternating, I will get something like tag1 twice then tag2 twice.
The Number of interrupt triggers is correct, but it will show me randomly tag1 or tag2. There seems to be some sort of buffer that gives the old id on a new interrupt trigger (but not always).

Thanks & sorry for my bad english

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import serial
import MySQLdb
import sys
import os
from thread import start_new_thread

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(24, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
UART = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyAMA0", 9600)
UART.open()
success = 0


def cls():
    os.system(['clear', 'cls'][os.name == 'nt'])

cls()


def mysqlex(sqlquery):
    global success
    db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="xxx", passwd="xxx", db="xxx")
    cur = db.cursor()
    try:
        cur.execute(sqlquery)
        db.commit()
        success = cur.fetchone()
        print success
    except:
        db.rollback()
        success = None
        print "no success"
    cur.close()
    db.close()


def led():
    GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setwarnings(False)
    GPIO.output(18, False)
    time.sleep(3)
    GPIO.output(18, True)


def interrupt(channel):
    start = "\x02"
    ende = "\x03"
    while True:
        ID = ""
        state = UART.read()
        if state == start:
            for Counter in range(13):
                zeichen = UART.read()
                ID += str(zeichen)
#            UART.flushInput()
            ID = ID.replace(start, "")
            ID = ID.replace(ende, "")
            print "ID -->", ID
            rfid = int(ID, 16)
            print "+********************************+"
            print rfid
            sql = "SELECT * FROM Rfid WHERE rfid_key = ('%s')" % rfid
            mysqlex(sql)
            if success is not None:
                start_new_thread(led, ())
                print "Zugang erlaubt                   +"
                print "+********************************+"
                print " "
                return
            else:
                print "Zugang verweigert                +"
                print "+********************************+"
                print " "
                return


GPIO.add_event_detect(24, GPIO.RISING, callback=interrupt, bouncetime=3000)


def main():
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main()

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        sys.exit()

    finally:
       GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: Hi Conwallace, kannst du mir bitte sagen was bei Dir auf pin 24 liegt? Hast du da einen Schalter? Am liebsten wäre es mir, wenn dass NFC board bei ranhalten eines Tags schon etwas (GPIO.RISING) sendet, meinst du das ist möglich?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer.

```
UART.flushInput()
```

before

```
if state == start:
```

and it works like a charm.